# Configuration JDBC Glassfish

Tags: mysql, jdbc, glassfish

I'm trying to create a database using MySql with glassfish, but when I want to create JDBC connection pool, I get this exception.

[image: Internal Server Error]

Comment: Please show us your relevant code and the full stack trace (as text, not as image).

Comment: That would be nice to provide the text version of error messages, instead of screenshots

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in GlassFish 4.1.1 see https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21314. This is fixed in the nightly builds of GlassFish 5.

Alternatively you can try Payara Server which is derived from GlassFish 4.1.1 which doesn't have the bug. See http://www.payara.fish/downloads